# Redirect all ports to my server in a simple way

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I have a server with SSH access (on port 22 and 443).

My ISP block  everything except ports 80 and 443.

I there a simple way to make everything go to my server (via SSH) then return the response via the same SSH connection, but in a way I can use all the ports in my client.

Like : Me → SSH connection → My server → request → Server → My server → Me

It's like a VPN but I don't have any port available for a VPN (443 is already taken by SSH).

Comment: Get another ISP? That behaviour is unacceptable from an ISP.

Comment: Problem is... I don't have any choice, it's that or tethering with my EDGE connection!

Answer (score 3):

You would need OpenVPN to do this. The good news is, OpenVPN and SSH play well together.

OpenVPN can use an existing SSH connection for tunneling. See more at http://www.classy.dk/hacks/archives/002287.html and http://www.anonyproz.com/openvpnsshtunnel.pdf